# Build de android de expo se congela en el splash pero funciona en desarrollo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Estoy haciendo una aplicación sencilla de 3 screens para una necesidad en especifico.
El problema es que ahora que la aplicación está terminada y funcionando correctamente en el ambiente de desarrollo no funciona al hacer la compilación.

El metro bundle no me tira ninguna clase de error cuando reviso la app, existirá alguna otra manera de debuggear el apk para saber dónde está el error?

**¿Que he intentado ya?**

Estaba utilizando SDK 48 y estoy utilizando expo-firebase-recaptcha había leído que en el SDK 48 ya no se utiliza por lo que hice el downgrade de SDK48 a SDK47 pero esto no funcionó

Mi package.json

```js
{
  "name": "yoreparto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.14",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "1.3.5",
    "expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^2.3.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "firebase": "^9.22.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.1",
    "expo-firebase-core": "~6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Y mi App.js

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
import AppContainer from './pages/MainNavigation';
import { PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: Constants.manifest.extra.apiKey,
  authDomain: Constants.manifest.extra.authDomain,
  projectId: Constants.manifest.extra.projectId,
  storageBucket: Constants.manifest.extra.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: Constants.manifest.extra.messagingSenderId,
  appId: Constants.manifest.extra.appId
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    initLoad()
  }, []);
  

  const initLoad = async () => {
    try {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        Regular: require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"),
        Bold: require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf"),
        SemiBold: require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf"),
        Italic: require("./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf"),
        NunitoBold: require("./assets/fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Bold.ttf"),
        Nunito: require("./assets/fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Regular.ttf"),
      });
      setLoading(true);
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  
  if(!loading) return null;

  return (
    <PaperProvider>
      <AppContainer/>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```